# PostGIS on WSL2 - extension "postgis" has no installation script nor update path for version X.X.X

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to add PostGIS extension to a postgresql database on my WSL2 (with Ubuntu 20.04) for a django project.

I have already installed postgresql, postgis and all dependencies with the following:

```
sudo apt -y install postgresql-12 postgresql-client-12
sudo apt install postgis postgresql-12-postgis-3
sudo apt-get install postgresql-12-postgis-3-scripts
```

And everything worked fine.

In postgresql, I have already created my db and connected to it:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -p 5432 -h 127.0.0.1 

postgres=# CREATE DATABASE dbname;
postgres=# \c dbname;
```

But then, when I try to add the postGIS extension with:

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

I get the following error:

**ERROR:  extension "postgis" has no installation script nor update path for version "3.1.0"**

And despite searching for similar questions on stackoverflow, I couldn't find any satisfactory solution for my case. Any idea what it could be wrong and how I can solve it? thank you!

EDIT:
Following command

```
ls $(pg_config --sharedir)/extension/postgis*
```

I get the following list of files:

```
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.0.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.0.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.0.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.0.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.0.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.0.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.0.6--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.0.7--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.1.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.1.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.1.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.1.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.1.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.1.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.1.6--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.1.7--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.1.8--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.1.9--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.2.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.2.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.2.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.2.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.2.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.2.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.2.6--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.2.7--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.2.8--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.3.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.3.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.3.10--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.3.11--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.3.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.3.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.3.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.3.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.3.6--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.3.7--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.3.8--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.3.9--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.4.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.4.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.4.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.4.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.4.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.4.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.4.6--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.4.7--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.4.8--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.4.9--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.5.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.5.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.5.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.5.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.5.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--2.5.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--3.0.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--3.0.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--3.0.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--3.0.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--3.1.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--3.1.0--3.1.0next.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--3.1.0dev--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--3.1.0next--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--ANY--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--unpackaged--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--unpackaged.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis.control
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.0.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.0.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.0.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.0.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.0.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.0.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.0.6--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.0.7--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.1.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.1.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.1.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.1.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.1.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.1.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.1.6--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.1.7--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.1.8--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.1.9--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.2.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.2.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.2.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.2.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.2.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.2.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.2.6--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.2.7--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.2.8--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.3.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.3.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.3.10--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.3.11--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.3.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.3.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.3.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.3.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.3.6--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.3.7--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.3.8--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.3.9--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.4.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.4.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.4.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.4.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.4.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.4.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.4.6--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.4.7--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.4.8--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.4.9--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.5.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.5.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.5.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.5.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.5.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--2.5.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--3.0.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--3.0.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--3.0.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--3.0.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--3.1.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--3.1.0--3.1.0next.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--3.1.0dev--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--3.1.0next--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--ANY--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--unpackaged--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster--unpackaged.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_raster.control
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.0.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.0.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.0.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.0.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.0.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.0.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.0.6--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.0.7--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.1.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.1.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.1.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.1.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.1.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.1.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.1.6--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.1.7--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.1.8--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.1.9--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.2.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.2.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.2.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.2.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.2.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.2.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.2.6--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.2.7--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.2.8--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.3.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.3.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.3.10--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.3.11--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.3.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.3.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.3.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.3.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.3.6--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.3.7--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.3.8--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.3.9--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.4.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.4.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.4.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.4.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.4.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.4.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.4.6--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.4.7--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.4.8--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.4.9--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.5.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.5.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.5.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.5.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.5.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--2.5.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--3.0.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--3.0.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--3.0.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--3.0.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--3.1.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--3.1.0--3.1.0next.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--3.1.0dev--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--3.1.0next--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--ANY--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder--unpackaged--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_tiger_geocoder.control
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.0.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.0.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.0.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.0.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.0.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.0.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.0.6--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.0.7--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.1.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.1.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.1.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.1.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.1.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.1.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.1.6--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.1.7--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.1.8--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.1.9--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.2.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.2.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.2.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.2.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.2.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.2.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.2.6--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.2.7--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.2.8--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.3.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.3.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.3.10--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.3.11--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.3.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.3.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.3.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.3.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.3.6--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.3.7--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.3.8--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.3.9--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.4.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.4.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.4.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.4.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.4.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.4.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.4.6--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.4.7--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.4.8--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.4.9--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.5.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.5.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.5.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.5.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.5.4--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--2.5.5--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--3.0.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--3.0.1--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--3.0.2--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--3.0.3--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--3.1.0--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--3.1.0--3.1.0next.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--3.1.0dev--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--3.1.0next--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--ANY--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--unpackaged--3.1.0.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology--unpackaged.sql
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis_topology.control
```

Content of postgis.control:

```
comment = 'PostGIS geometry and geography spatial types and functions'
default_version = '3.1.0'
module_pathname = '$libdir/postgis-3'
relocatable = false
```

Comment: Then the extension was not installed correctly, and some of the *.sql files are missing.

Comment: and how can I check that?

Comment: With the correct `pg_config` in the `PATH`, execute `ls $(pg_config --sharedir)/extension/postgis*`. Perhaps you are connected to a database in a different version.

Comment: By running this command, I get a long list of files named:
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--X.X.X--X.X.X.sql (some of them are 2.X.X, some of them are 3.X.X)

Comment: For example for the 3.0.0 version, I see the following files:
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--3.0.0.sql 
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--ANY--3.0.0.sql 
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis--unpackaged--3.0.0.sql  
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis-3.control

Comment: [edit] the question and show all these files.

Comment: Done! I've edited the post with the list of files

Comment: Thanks. That looks good. Can you run `\dx` and see if `postgis` is already installed?

Comment: Ah! It seems not.
In fact, I get only the following extensions installed:

- plpgsql

So I suppose I didn't install postgis correctly..

Comment: No, on the contrary: that's just as it is supposed to be. If you were connected to the same database where you got the error, I'm out of explanations. That would require personal investigation.

Comment: Ok.. thanks. I'm trying to re-install everything from scratch anyway since I'm out of ideas too

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Do you know how can I tell postgresql to search for a different version of postgis?

Because I have re-installed everything with the latest versions (postgresql 13 and postgis 3.1.0), but when I run the "create extension postgis" command I keep getting:
ERROR:  extension "postgis" has no installation script nor update path for version "3.0.0"

How can I tell it to look for version 3.1.0?

Comment: Ah. Then you must have an extra PostGIS package installed. Get rid of that.

Comment: Sorry, how can I check that?

Comment: even trying with 'CREATE EXTENSION postgis VERSION "3.1.0";' gives me the same error though... (no installation script nor update path)

Comment: Use `dpkg -l | grep postgis` to get a list of installed PostGIS packages.

Comment: If I do it, I only have the following list:
1) postgresql-12-postgis-3 (v3.1.0) 2) postgresql-12-postgis-3-scripts (v3.1.0)... so it seems to me that only 1 version is installed..

Comment: Looks like it yes. At any rate, it seems like your `postgis.control` file specified that the default version is 3.0.0. Can you confirm that?

Comment: Yes. But, know I've removed and re-installed postgis (3.1.0) from source - so the "3.0.0" version is no longer there anymore. In fact, now in my postgis.control I see "default_version = '3.1.0'". The files in the folder are all 3.1.0 version, so everything seems coherent to me.. but still, getting the same error in postgres, even if I try with "'CREATE EXTENSION postgis VERSION "3.1.0";', I get the error "no installation script nor update path for version 3.1.0".

Comment: To me, it seems the files are properly installed, but somehow postgres keep not seeing them for some reason...

Comment: I just see that there is a file `postgis.control` and `postgis-3.control` in the list in your question. Could you [edit] the question and post the contents of these files? Particularly the `postgis-3.control` file looks fishy; I don't think it should be there.

Comment: As I said this morning I removed and re-installed from source the 3.1.0 only, so the list of files has changed (edited in the original post). The postgis-3.control file is no longer there indeed, there is only a 'postgis.control'. I've edited the question to add its content also.

Comment: That one looks fine, and it will *not* try to install version 3.0.0.

Comment: Yes but the problem is, even if I run ''CREATE EXTENSION postgis VERSION "3.1.0";' ", I get the error 'extension "postgis" has no installation script nor update path for version "3.1.0"'... so I get this error regardless of which version I'm using..

Comment: I have given up on this - I would have to look at the database.

Comment: @Damian Have you fixed this and do you remember how?

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this here for people using **pgAdmin**.

I tried to install PostGis via right-click Extensions -> CREATE

In the dialog I had no selection "postgis" just "postgis-3". I tried that and got the error message `error extension postgis 3 has no installation script nor update path for version` that lead me to this SO Post.

But using the SQL Tool instead of the Dialog worked!

- right-click on your database
- query tool
- `CREATE EXTENSION postgis CASCADE;`

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but I came across this today as I faced exactly the same problem.

I found that I had three different clusters online (from running pg_lsclusters) and that my psql session was connecting to a different one than postgis installed to.  The postgis 3.1.4 extension setup files were going to my postgres 14 (/usr/share/postgresql/14/extension/) and psql was connecting to my postgres12 by default.  Copying the setup files from one to the other didn't work.

At least I was able to identify the port using `pg_lsclusters` and pass the `-p` option to `psql`, then my script containing "CREATE EXTENSION postgis" ran fine.

Will comment again if I improve on this.

UPDATE: I've resolved to creating a file `~/.postgresqlrc` to direct postgresql to default to the version I want (where postgis installed), containing contents:

```
14 main postgres
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR version**... try restarting the postgresql service.

**The details...**

In my case, it's just Linux, not WSL. But the situation looks the same. The control file is there (which tells it which version it looks for), and the install sql file (in the original post that's `postgis--3.1.0.sql`) is there, but the error says it is not. I am using `psql` to run the `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` command.

I wanted a specific postgis version, so I built a tgz from source and installed that. (perhaps this is why no postinstall hook restarted postgres...maybe WSL is the same in this way, even though apt-get was used). I had a different error at first:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/${postgres_version}/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

That file was missing in the package, but I found it in the source tree, so I copied that in, and then got the same error as in the original post:

```
ERROR:  extension "postgis" has no installation script nor update path for version "${postgis_version}"
```

So, I fiddled around, saw the sql file for the installation existed at the right path

```
/usr/share/postgresql/${postgres_version}/extension/postgis--${postgis_version}.sql
```

Based on that, I figured there was nothing needed... the right files are where they need to be. So eventually just took a guess and restarted the postgresql server, and then `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` worked.